# How can I create custom EV3 blocks (developer mode)?

Tags: ev3, programming

What do I need to create custom blocks and in particular the VIX part?

Comment: Would be great if someone could create a MQTT custom block.

Answer (score 6):

You only need the official LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software.

LEGO provides a "EV3 Block Developer Kit" on the MINDSTORMS [downloads page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads). This contains some minimal instructions on creating blocks. It also contains an older version of the EV3 software.

However, I have found that any version of the MINDSTORMS software can be used in "developer mode" by creating a file named `MindstormsEV3.ini` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Tokens DeveloperMode="True" />
```

Save this file in the directory where the software is installed, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\LEGO Software\LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition\`, then start the software.

Comment: This works. Drop a Block to a Program and double-click the block to inspect its .vix internals. Now you are in LabView edit mode.

Comment: When trying to save a .vix -- even a new Project and new .vix -- I get a "Unexpected error during save. Is the file read-only?". (Win7 SP1. file permission should not be the issue).

Comment: With a fresh copy of Lego Mindstorms Home Edition or Education, the error went away, but the save action is not saving the edited .vix back to disc. Any ideas?

Comment: Use *Export...* on the *Developer* menu to save the .vix file to disk.

Answer (score -2):

For input output you can use the OtherFiles Folder> EV3 and import the PBricks primitive.