# Labview Developer mode for EV3 Classroom app

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, labview

I found a [trick to enable labview mode on EV3 Home Edition](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8773/21801), however, I cannot find the `LEGO Software` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)` (or `C:\Program Files`). In fact, I can't even `Open file location` on the app itself! Is there a workaround for this? I may have downloaded the app from Microsoft Store, I'm not sure...